# PHP Hover action

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Building the site out at http://nelsonkeating.com/

When hovering over an image you will see 3 actions appear. How can I remove these, and instead just display the title of the page when the user hovers (the title is currently right below the image)

*This is a wordpress site.

Thanks!

Comment: Explain why you are downvoting this, otherwise they have no way to improve the question.

Comment: Didn't downvote, But showing the code could definitely help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputted HTML looks like this (after a lot of output cleanup):

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <a href="http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/"><img width="310" height="206" src="http://nelsonkeating.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/whit-and-me-park-310x206.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="whit and me park" title="whit and me park" /></a>
    <div class="actions">                           
        <a href="http://nelsonkeating.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/whit-and-me-park.png" rel="gallery" title="What We Do" class="view">Enlarge</a>
        <a class="share">Share</a>
        <a href="http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/#comments" class="comment"><span>0</span> Comment</a>
        <div class="share-container">
            <div class="share-icons">
                <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="twitter-share iframe" onClick="twitPop('http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/', 'What We Do - ', 'sawyerh:Best Designer Alive')">Twitter</a>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/&amp;t=What We Do" class="facebook-share" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
                <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/&amp;title=What We Do" class="stumble-share" target="_blank">StumbleUpon</a>
                <a href="http://technorati.com/cosmos/search.html?url=http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/" class="tech-share" target="_blank">Technorati</a>
                <a href="http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&amp;url=http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/&amp;title=What We Do" class="digg-share" target="_blank">Digg</a>
                <a href="http://del.icio.us/post?url=http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/&amp;title=What We Do" class="delicious-share" target="_blank">Delicious</a>
                <a href="mailto:EMAIL?body=http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/" class="email-share" target="_blank">Email</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- #share-container -->        
    </div><!-- #actions --> 
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div><!-- #img-container -->
<h2><a href="http://nelsonkeating.com/why-were-here/" title="What We Do" rel="bookmark">What We Do</a></h2>
```

So, there are a few things to note here. The `actions` div looks like it is the one that is being displayed on hover. The `<h2>` is what you want to show. So, the hacky thing to do is to just put the `<h2>` generation inside the `actions` div and comment out (or remove) that code.

A better solution is to, in addition to that, dig through the jQuery and make sure you aren't breaking any of that code on hover. Also, since I can only guess this is a theme, there might be a few issues that crop up because of this. Themes are usually pretty tightly constructed (in my experience at least) and changing something can have a cascading effect.

Answer (score 1):

IF you see your html for each of these containers it's in the form of:

```
<div class="img-container">
     <a href="http://nelsonkeating.com/whitney-danielle/"><img width="310" height="315" src="http://nelsonkeating.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/DW3-310x315.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="D&amp;W3" title="D&amp;W3" /></a>

     <div class="actions">


                         <a href="http://nelsonkeating.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/DW3.jpg" rel="gallery" title="Whitney &#038; Danielle" class="view">Enlarge</a>



                         <a class="share">Share</a>   

                                                        <a href="http://nelsonkeating.com/whitney-danielle/#comments" class="comment"><span>0</span> Comment</a> 

                                                       <div class="share-container">
                            <div class="share-icons">
                                                                    <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="twitter-share iframe" onClick="twitPop('http://nelsonkeating.com/whitney-danielle/', 'Whitney &#038; Danielle - ', 'sawyerh:Best Designer Alive')">
                                Twitter</a>

                                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://nelsonkeating.com/whitney-danielle/&amp;t=Whitney &#038; Danielle" class="facebook-share" target="_blank">

                                Facebook</a>

                                <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://nelsonkeating.com/whitney-danielle/&amp;title=Whitney &#038; Danielle" class="stumble-share" target="_blank">
                                StumbleUpon</a>

                                <a href="http://technorati.com/cosmos/search.html?url=http://nelsonkeating.com/whitney-danielle/" class="tech-share" target="_blank">
                                Technorati</a>

                                <a href="http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&amp;url=http://nelsonkeating.com/whitney-danielle/&amp;title=Whitney &#038; Danielle" class="digg-share" target="_blank">
                                Digg</a>


                                <a href="http://del.icio.us/post?url=http://nelsonkeating.com/whitney-danielle/&amp;title=Whitney &#038; Danielle" class="delicious-share" target="_blank">
                                Delicious</a>

                                <a href="mailto:EMAIL?body=http://nelsonkeating.com/whitney-danielle/" class="email-share" target="_blank">
                                Email</a>
                            </div>
                         </div><!-- #share-container -->        
                    </div><!-- #actions --> 
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div><!-- #img-container -->
```

Without knowing how the script is exactly working i would suggest you modify the content inside the `actions` class which is revealed on hover